# Proper definition of "this" keyword in c++?

Tags: c++, oop

I am learning some theory behind OOP C++ programming. Our professor provided us with some sample questions so that we could make a revision before an exam. Could you please take a look and check if my understanding of this term is correct? I would be really thankful for any advices.

```
The this keyword:
a) Inside a constructor, it is a reference to currently constructed object. (false)
b) In the method, it is a reference to the object for which it was called (true)
c) Inside the constructor it is a pointer to currently constructed object. (false)
d) In the method, it is a pointer to the object for which it was called. (false)
```

Comment: `this` is a pointer, not a reference.

Comment: And it does work in a constructor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To put it somewhat simple (that doesn't include virtual function complexity here):

`this` is a *pointer* that points to the object that was constructed and this the first parameter passed to any non static member function.

So for example,

```
class X  { void foo() {} } ;
X x;
```

When you do `x.foo()`, foo()'s first invisible parameter is equal to `&x`. When you do `x.foo()`, you are actually doing `foo(&x)` at the assembly level.

The constructor techically (at the assembly level) is just a function like any other member function, the only difference is that it's called on object construction. It also takes the this pointer like any other non-static member.

So, your questions, c) and d) are true.

Comment: technically the constructor is not a function like other member functions. For example it has no name, you cannot get a member function pointer to it...

Comment: @idclev463035818 at the assembly level there are no names, only pointers.

Comment: and still you cannot get a pointer to a constructor, while you can for member functions

Comment: @idclev463035818 that's a C++ feature, not at the assembly level. If C++ allowed, you could take a pointer to the constructor because it is as static as any other function.

Comment: the question is about C++ not assembly

Comment: I had to include technical details to explain what's going on with `this`.

Comment: its fine, i made a suggestion for improvement, you changed the question, no need to argue any further

Comment: the assembly level doesn't define the rules of C++. Technically, at the assembly level, member functions are just like non-member functions, yet you can't use `this` in a non-member function. Also `const` local variables are just like non-`const` local variables, yet you can't modify them.

Comment: @user253751 there is a difference in const/non const, when the const variable is placed in a memory area that cannot be changed, then you cannot alter it. This is at the CPU level.

Comment: @MichaelChourdakis generally not for local (non-static) variables.